# Pattern matching in case expressions/list comprehensions

Tags: haskell, pattern-matching, list-comprehension

Why does the following attempt to pattern-match in a list comprehension not work?

Example: simultaneous substitution of atoms in a term data type.

The data type:

```
data Term a 
    = Atom a
    | Compound (Term a) (Term a)
    deriving Show
```

The substitution algorithm for atoms in terms (picks the first matching substitution if any and ignores the rest):

```
subs :: [(Term a, Term a)] -> Term a -> Term a
subs subList term = case term of 
    atom@(Atom x)       ->  let substitutions = 
                                [ s | s@(Atom x, _) <- subList ]
                            in  if null substitutions
                                then atom
                                else snd . head $ substitutions
    (Compound t1 t2)    -> Compound (subs subList t1) (subs subList t2)
```

Some test data:

```
subList = [((Atom 'a'), Compound (Atom 'b') (Atom 'c'))]
term1 = Atom 'a' 
term2 = Atom 'x'
```

Running the example results in:

```
>: subs subList term1
Compound (Atom 'b') (Atom 'c')
```

which is the desired behaviour, and

```
>: subs subList term2
Compound (Atom 'b') (Atom 'c')
```

which is not.

Strangley explicit matching works:

```
subs'' :: [(Term Char, Term Char)] -> Term Char -> Term Char
subs'' subList term = case term of 
    atom@(Atom _)       ->  let substitutions = 
                            [ s | s@(Atom 'a', _) <- subList ]
                            in  if null substitutions
                                then atom
                                else snd . head $ substitutions
    (Compound t1 t2)    -> Compound (subs subList t1) (subs subList t2)

subs''' subList term = case term of 
     atom@(Atom _)       ->  let substitutions = 
                             [ s | s@(Atom 'x', _) <- subList ]
                             in  if null substitutions
                                 then atom
                                 else snd . head $ substitutions
     (Compound t1 t2)    -> Compound (subs subList t1) (subs subList t2)
```

feed with the test data result in:

`>: subs'' subList term1` or `>: subs'' subList term2`
`Compound (Atom 'b') (Atom 'c')`

`>: subs''' subList term1` or `>: subs''' subList term2`
`Atom 'x'`

What am I missing?

Comment: To avoid falling into this error in the future, I'd recommend to turn on GHC warnings with `-Wall`: this would point out that `x` is being bound twice (the inner `x` shadows the outer one).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Haskell has linear patterns, meaning that there must be no repeated variables in patterns. Also, pattern variables in inner expressions shadow outer variables, instead of establishing equality of identical variables.

You're trying to do something like this:

```
charEq :: Char -> Char -> Bool
charEq c c = True
charEq _ _ = False
```

But this is an error because of the repeated variables. If we move the second `c` to an inner expression, it compiles, but it still doesn't work as intended:

```
charEq :: Char -> Char -> Bool
charEq c d = case d of
  c -> True
  _ -> False
```

Here the inner `c` is just a new variable that shadows the outer `c`, so `charEq` always returns `True`.

If we'd like to check for equality we must use `==` explicitly:

```
subs :: [(Term a, Term a)] -> Term a -> Term a
subs subList term = case term of 
    atom@(Atom x)       ->  let substitutions = 
                                [ s | s@(Atom x', _) <- subList, x == x' ]
                            in  if null substitutions
                                then atom
                                else snd . head $ substitutions
    (Compound t1 t2)    -> Compound (subs subList t1) (subs subList t2)
```

Comment: thank you very much ... if I understand correctly it's necessary that `a` is an instance of `Eq` under any circumstances?

Comment: @jules yes. One reason for why we don't have equality testing in patterns is because not all types are instances of `Eq`. I guess it could be still implemented as syntactic sugar, but no one really thought it worth the hassle.